# Hibernate XML mapping or Annotation mapping config better for real time project using spring framework

Tags: spring, hibernate

Please let me know which one is better for real time project Hibernate XML Mapping or Annotation base Mapping ?

Comment: It is really a matter of taste, and what you are more comfortable using.

Comment: Actually the  question got from interviewer

Comment: What are you defining as a "real time" project?  I think in general the XML would give you finer grain control; not sure if you would even that however.

Comment: real time i mean it (a client level project)   I think in general the XML would give you finer grain control -> I think XML give more control

Comment: annotation is better for real time project

Answer (score 0):

For new projects better to use annotations, because XML mapping doesn't support all features that annotation mapping does.